# Check if character in string is an integer, and if so grab that int

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I am currently on the codewars site trying to improve my JavaScript along with other things. This question will give an input like this
`'is2 Thi1s T4est 3a'` and expect an output like this `'Thi1s is2 3a T4est'`

I am having trouble indexing the string. It seems odd as I've done it before in Python but even trying this in Python I don't get the proper output.

Here is my code, before it was giving me at least an array of the numbers but now I just get `[ Array(4) ]`.

I know that the proper output should be a string but once I get it all in an array I plan to just `tempSentence.join(" ")` the array and return it. Sorry that is kind of messy but I kept trying different things:

```
function order(words){
    let hasNumber = /\d/;
    let newSentence = words.split(" ")
    let tempSentence = words.split(" ")

    for (let i = 0; i < newSentence.length; i++){
      for (let j = 0; j < newSentence[i].length; j++){
        if (hasNumber.test(newSentence[i][j])){
          tempSentence[words[i][j]-1] = newSentence[i]
        }
      }
    }
    return tempSentence
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating two separate arrays and trying to rearrange indicies in a nested loop seems quite convoluted for what you're trying to accomplish. An easier approach would be to take just one array of words, and `.sort` it by having a helper function that extracts the digit from it, and comparing the extracted number of the two elements being compared inside the callback.

```js
const getNum = word => word.match(/\d+/)[0];
const order = (words) => words
  .split(' ')
  .sort((a, b) => getNum(a) - getNum(b))
  .join(' ');
console.log(order('is2 Thi1s T4est 3a'));
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks a bunch! Like I said I'm new to Javascript and haven't fully wrapped my head around arrow functions and their power yet.  What are you doing within sort with the a and b though?

Comment: The sort callback takes two arguments - two (essentially random) elements from the array that are being compared. Whether the return value from the callback is positive or negative determines whether the first argument gets sorted before or after the second argument. So, subtracting the difference with the `getNum` call on each will give you the positive/negative comparison that you need.

Comment: Makes sense thank you, I was having trouble understanding sort's  arguments the other night